# Card Component wont re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For some reason, my card won't re-render when I make a call to the API.
when the information updates in the backend it doesn't display in the front unless I refresh the app.

I'm passing down info as a prop and grabbing the company name, address, and phone.

```
const CpoCard = ({ info, navigation }) => {
  const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState(info.companies[0].companyName);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(info.companies[0].city);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState(info.companies[0].phoneNumber);
  const [employeeID, setEmployeeID] = useState(info.userId.employeeId);

  const { setSelectedEmployee } = useCompany();

  const handleEditPress = () => {
    setSelectedEmployee(info);
    navigation.navigate('DeleteEmployee');
    //deleteEmployee
  };

  const handlePress = () => {
    console.log(info);
    navigation.navigate('CpoInfo', { info: info });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
      {
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <View style={styles.mainContent}>
            <Image
              style={styles.employeeImg}
              source={require('~assets/pngs/avatar.png')}
            />

            <View style={styles.companyInfoContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                  {companyName !== null ? `${companyName} ` : 'info'}
                </Text>
                <Text>{`Phone Number: ${phoneNumber}`}</Text>
                <Text>{`address: ${address}`}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      }
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you post how this card component is being used.

Comment: Where are you making the API call and passing the props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the prop `info` is being updated by the parent component, the `CpoCard` will re-render. You could simply test it by including `console.log('rerendered)` in the component.

Based on your wording in your question it seems the issue isint the re-render but more likely your structure of a `CpoCard` component.

**In React**, whenever the component first loads, it creates its states to whatever initial value you set in `useState`. Later down the line the state will not mutate nor charge unless the setter function is called. That triggers the component to re-render. You can NOT set the state value otherwise.

In your case, in the `CpoCard` component, the prop `info` is ONLY used to set the initial state value via `useState(info.companies[0].companyName)`. So the value is being set on the first load of a component. But later on, regardless how `info` prop changes - the state will NOT change regardless of how many times the component re-renders.

**Simple example:**
At `CpoCard` load `<CpoCard info={'initial value'} />` -> component `CpoCard` creates a state via `useState` and stores its value as passed `const [info, setinfo] = useState(props.info)` -> component renders.

Later down the line `info` prop changes `<CpoCard info={'second value'} />` -> component `CpoCard` re-renders `info` from `const [info, setinfo] = useState(props.info)` remains the initial value `'initial value'` since you can not change the state value like so. The initial value will remain for the entire time, regardless of how many re-renders, unless called the setter `setInfo` and changes.

**So in your case your structure is the issue.**
I am unsure why you even store each individual prop into its own state - it seems like a flaw in a structure by itself. If you are getting passed values - use those. If for some reason you actually require to use a state for each value then there is also a work around - `useEffect`

`useEffect` hook allows you to listen to changes and react based on that.
So you should call each setter in a `useEffect` that is listening to your `info` prop change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCompanyName(info.companies[0].companyName)
    setAddress(info.companies[0].city)
    setPhoneNumber(info.companies[0].phoneNumber)
    setEmployeeID(info.userId.employeeId)
}, [info])
```

With this `useEffect` what happens is the component loads the initial value, stores it in state and renders. Whenever the `prop.info` changes the component re-renders, the `useEffect` dependency array (the `[]` in the end) checks that `prop.info` changes hence it executes the function (the code inside the `useEffect` hook) that sets the states based on new `info` prop and that causes a component to re-render once again displaying the new data.